# Modeling Interest rates based on another rates

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

Below plots shows Red and Blue lines, those represents 2 different interest rates products.
I have a forecast for the Blue line, how can I create the same for the Red line?

I have noticed that there is a very strong correlation between them. Next, I have decided to verify the spread between those 2 lines and assume that the historical spread should be similar in the future. E.g historical spread on the average is 0.1% then if Blue line hit 1% [in the future] we get 0.9% for the Red. Next, I can repaeat for another tenors: 1 week, 3 months, 1 year etc.

On the other hand, I think that working independently for each tenor I may miss some part of information. It is obvious that if there is a real interest rate shock it will imapct 1 day/1month/1year interest rates product.

Could you please give me some hints/key words for such analysis?

[image: Rates]

Comment: Hi: I think you would need to explain in more detail what you're doing because there are so many arbitrage relationships between interest rates. Also, I think it's better to ask this question on economics.stackexchange or quant.stackexchange.com. But, as it stands, I don't think you would get much response at those places either unless you provide more specifics. For example, what is blue line ? What is red-line ? etc.

Comment: Is that dollar LIBOR and SOFR shown at monthly points?  If so, the relationship is that both reflect short-term interest rates but SOFR is usually but not always lower since it is an overnight rate.  You could make the series longer and finer, but any forecast for future LIBOR would be slightly dubious given that it is being abolished

Comment: Yes, this is SOFR and LIBOR  - nice shoot! :) The true reason for this analysis is that I have some forecasts for LIBOR but not for SOFR and I need both for this year. So all is about Forecasts for SOFR or rather the proxy for that.